# How to insert row in a dataframe based on columns value with condition?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a DataFrame with ~20k lines which looks like that:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'Car_ID': ['B332', 'B332', 'B332', 'C315', 'C315', 'C315', 'C315', 'C315', 'F310', 'F310'], \
                    'Date': ['2018-03-12', '2018-03-14', '2018-03-15', '2018-03-17', '2018-03-13', '2018-03-15', \
                             '2018-03-18', '2018-03-21', '2018-03-10', '2018-03-13'], \
                    'Driver': ['Alex', 'Alex', 'Mick', 'Sara', 'Sara', 'Jean', 'Sara', 'Sara', 'Franck','Michel']})
df

Out:    
    Car_ID  Date        Driver
0   B332    2018-03-12  Alex
1   B332    2018-03-14  Alex
2   B332    2018-03-15  Mick
3   C315    2018-03-17  Sara
4   C315    2018-03-13  Sara
5   C315    2018-03-15  Jean
6   C315    2018-03-18  Sara
7   C315    2018-03-21  Sara
8   F310    2018-03-10  Franck
9   F310    2018-03-13  Michel
```

I create a new colomn for each event in my dataframe like this:

```
df["Event"] = np.where(df.Car_ID.str.contains('B', case=True, na=False), 'Rent_Car_B', \
                    np.where(df.Car_ID.str.contains('C', case=True, na=False), 'Rent_Car_C', \
                    np.where(df.Car_ID.str.contains('F', case=True, na=False), 'Rent_Car_F', df.Car_ID))) 
df

Out:
    Car_ID  Date        Driver  Event
0   B332    2018-03-12  Alex    Rent_Car_B
1   B332    2018-03-14  Alex    Rent_Car_B
2   B332    2018-03-15  Mick    Rent_Car_B
3   C315    2018-03-17  Sara    Rent_Car_C
4   C315    2018-03-13  Sara    Rent_Car_C
5   C315    2018-03-15  Jean    Rent_Car_C
6   C315    2018-03-18  Sara    Rent_Car_C
7   C315    2018-03-21  Sara    Rent_Car_C
8   F310    2018-03-10  Franck  Rent_Car_F
9   F310    2018-03-13  Michel  Rent_Car_F
```

For my `Event` column I want to add new row for each driver changes like this:

```
Out:
    Car_ID  Date        Driver  Event
0   B332    2018-03-12  Alex    Rent_Car_B
1   B332    2018-03-14  Alex    Rent_Car_B
2   B332    2018-03-15  Mick    Rent_Car_B
3   B332    2018-03-15          Alex to Mick
4   C315    2018-03-17  Sara    Rent_Car_C
5   C315    2018-03-13  Sara    Rent_Car_C
6   C315    2018-03-15  Jean    Rent_Car_C
7   C315    2018-03-15          Sara to Jean
8   C315    2018-03-18  Sara    Rent_Car_C
9   C315    2018-03-18          Jean to Sara
10  C315    2018-03-21  Sara    Rent_Car_C
11  F310    2018-03-10  Franck  Rent_Car_F
12  F310    2018-03-13  Michel  Rent_Car_F
13  F310    2018-03-13          Franck to Mike
```

I'm not sure if there is some trick to realize this job. 
I would be greatful of your advices!

Comment: What is meant by 'Alex' appearing in both row 0 and 1?

Comment: First part - you can do `df['Event'] = 'Rent_Car_' + df['Car_ID'].str[0]`.

Comment: @Dillon it means that he drived the same car two days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `shift` method and first create a column with it that we will use after:

```
df['Driver_shift'] = df['Driver'].shift()
```

Select the row where you actually change of driver and same car_ID with the mask:

```
mask = (df['Driver'] != df['Driver_shift'])&(df['Car_ID'] == df['Car_ID'].shift())
df_change = df[mask]
```

Now, change the indexes by adding 0.5 for later concatenation and sorting, and change the value of two columns:

```
df_change = df_change.set_index(df_change.index+0.5)
df_change.loc[:,'Event'] = df_change['Driver_shift'] + ' to ' + df_change['Driver']
df_change['Driver'] = '' # to replace the value
```

Now you can concatenate, sort, reset_index and drop:

```
pd.concat([df,df_change]).sort_index().reset_index(drop=True).drop('Driver_shift',1)
```

and you get:

```
   Car_ID        Date  Driver             Event
0    B332  2018-03-12    Alex        Rent_Car_B
1    B332  2018-03-14    Alex        Rent_Car_B
2    B332  2018-03-15    Mick        Rent_Car_B
3    B332  2018-03-15              Alex to Mick
4    C315  2018-03-17    Sara        Rent_Car_C
5    C315  2018-03-13    Sara        Rent_Car_C
6    C315  2018-03-15    Jean        Rent_Car_C
7    C315  2018-03-15              Sara to Jean
8    C315  2018-03-18    Sara        Rent_Car_C
9    C315  2018-03-18              Jean to Sara
10   C315  2018-03-21    Sara        Rent_Car_C
11   F310  2018-03-10  Franck        Rent_Car_F
12   F310  2018-03-13  Michel        Rent_Car_F
13   F310  2018-03-13          Franck to Michel
```

EDIT: to add a row before each driver and date

```
df1 = df.copy()
df1.index = df1.index +0.5
df2 = pd.concat([df.drop('Event',1),df1]).sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)
df2['Event'] = df2['Event'].fillna(df2['Driver'])
```

the result is in df2

Comment: Hi @Ben.T How can I do the same job if the latest dates are at the top of datafrmae. Like this:

  `Car_ID  Date        Driver  Event
 0   F310    2018-03-13  Michel  Rent_Car_F
 1   F310    2018-03-10  Franck  Rent_Car_F
 2   C315    2018-03-21  Sara    Rent_Car_C
 3   C315    2018-03-18  Sara    Rent_Car_C
 4   C315    2018-03-15  Jean    Rent_Car_C
 5   C315    2018-03-13  Sara    Rent_Car_C
 6   C315    2018-03-17  Sara    Rent_Car_C
 7   B332    2018-03-15  Mick    Rent_Car_B
 8   B332    2018-03-14  Alex    Rent_Car_B
 9   B332    2018-03-12  Alex    Rent_Car_B`

Comment: @M-M and where do you want the extra row? for example Franck to Michel (or Michel to Franck): after Franck, before Michel, between both?

Comment: I resolved this problem. But I want to add a new row for each unique `Car_ID` and take the name of driver in Event column and add the date. something like this `Car_ID  Date        Driver  Event
 0   F310    2018-03-13  Michel  Michel
 1   F310    2018-03-13  Michel  Rent_Car_F`

Comment: I forgot to tag you :) @Ben.T

Comment: @M-M not sure I understand what you want at the final. I see for Michel you want to add a row before with the Driver name in the Event column, but what about for Franck you want to add a row too?

Comment: yeah I want to do the same for each distinct  Car_ID. @Ben.T

Comment: @M-M you mean for each Driver?

Comment: Yeah @Ben.T for each driver.

Comment: @M-M see the EDIT

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it and let you know @Ben.T!

Answer (score 3):

Its a pretty complicated problem here's my take :

```
# Add the Driver columns by shifting grouped by the Event
df['new'] =  df.groupby('Event').apply(lambda x : x['Driver'].shift(1) +'to'+ x['Driver']).values
# Split them by 'to'
df['new'] =df['new'].str.split('to').bfill()
# Check if both of them are equal
m = df['new'].str[0] != df['new'].str[1]
# Based on the condition create a new dataframe
new_df = df.loc[m].copy().iloc[:-1]
# Convert the list to the format you desired 
new_df['new'] = new_df['new'].str[0] + ' to ' + new_df['new'].str[1]
# Concat new dataframe and old dataframe 
mdf = pd.concat([df.drop('new',1) , new_df.drop(['Driver','Event'],1) \
               .rename(columns = {'new':'Event'})])


     Car_ID        Date  Driver             Event
0   B332  2018-03-12    Alex        Rent_Car_B
1   B332  2018-03-14    Alex        Rent_Car_B
2   B332  2018-03-15    Mick        Rent_Car_B
3   C315  2018-03-17    Sara        Rent_Car_C
4   C315  2018-03-13    Sara        Rent_Car_C
5   C315  2018-03-15    Jean        Rent_Car_C
6   C315  2018-03-18    Sara        Rent_Car_C
7   C315  2018-03-21    Sara        Rent_Car_C
8   F310  2018-03-10  Franck        Rent_Car_F
9   F310  2018-03-13  Michel        Rent_Car_F
2   B332  2018-03-15     NaN      Alex to Mick
5   C315  2018-03-15     NaN      Sara to Jean
6   C315  2018-03-18     NaN      Jean to Sara
8   F310  2018-03-10     NaN  Franck to Michel
```

If you want the order then sort the index i.e

```
mdf = mdf.sort_index()
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! @Dark

Answer (score 2):

You can do this pretty nicely with a few shifts! You can also get the indices correctly with this method and add them exactly where you want.

After you'e added `Event` do your `DataFrame`:

```
import pandas as pd

# Modify the index so we can later append to the correct rows
df.index= df.index*2

# Determine when switches occur
mask = (df.Driver != df.Driver.shift(1)) & (df.Car_ID == df.Car_ID.shift(1))
sw_from = df[mask.shift(-1).fillna(False)].copy()
sw_to = df[mask].copy()

# Make the switching rows have the correct information
sw_to['Event'] = sw_from.Driver.values + ' to ' + sw_to.Driver.values
sw_to['Driver'] = ''

# Modify the switching indices so they get added to the proper position
sw_to.index = sw_to.index+1

# Add them to df
df = df.append(sw_to).sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

Output:

```
   Car_ID        Date  Driver             Event
0    B332  2018-03-12    Alex        Rent_Car_B
1    B332  2018-03-14    Alex        Rent_Car_B
2    B332  2018-03-15    Mick        Rent_Car_B
3    B332  2018-03-15              Alex to Mick
4    C315  2018-03-17    Sara        Rent_Car_C
5    C315  2018-03-13    Sara        Rent_Car_C
6    C315  2018-03-15    Jean        Rent_Car_C
7    C315  2018-03-15              Sara to Jean
8    C315  2018-03-18    Sara        Rent_Car_C
9    C315  2018-03-18              Jean to Sara
10   C315  2018-03-21    Sara        Rent_Car_C
11   F310  2018-03-10  Franck        Rent_Car_F
12   F310  2018-03-13  Michel        Rent_Car_F
13   F310  2018-03-13          Franck to Michel
```